# Selenium on windows form button click event - Windows form is no longer clickable after launching web browser

Tags: selenium-webdriver, c#

I was trying to integrate a selenium test with a windows form app.
Code works fine for a button click event.
But after chrome driver get open I cant click any thing at the windows form application.
Or I even cant drag or click on the windows form GUI.
What might be the reason?

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            var credentials = ReadCredentials();
   

            foreach (var credential in credentials)
            {

                driver = new ChromeDriver();

                driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://xxx.xx.com/");
                driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();

                driver.FindElement(By.Name("user_id")).SendKeys(credential.Item1);
                driver.FindElement(By.Name("password")).SendKeys(credential.Item2);

                driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[text()=\"Sign In\"]")).Click();
```